# Network share access denied on execute

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions, network-shares

Using Windows 10 Enterprise, version 1803, build 17134.165. When I run certain applications from a network share , I get "Windows cannot access \share\folder\application name", you do not have permission to access ... 
I have made myself a domain administrator, I have given the share level permissions and the folder level permission full access for any user. All PCs are joined to the domain and all user tested are domain users. The issue occurs even if the share is mapped to a drive or use runas administrator. I can delete files, folders, create them, rename them, etc.
I have remove all antivirus and disable windows defender as well. I am hoping someone knows what security feature in windows needs to be changed to resolve this.
What is interesting is that applications which produce screen output only work fine, but applications that access local resources such as get a list of drives, folders, printers, etc give the access denied error. Even more interesting is that this problem only occurs on this version of Windows 10. Have tested on Windows 7, 8 & 2016 and have no issues. There must be a security feature in this version of windows that needs to turn off...
[image]